# Why doesn't KVO observer get called on a sub object?

Tags: swift4, key-value-observing

With the following Swift playground, why does the observer inside `view` never get called?

```
import Foundation

@objc class Person: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var name = "Taylor Swift"
}

let taylor = Person()

taylor.observe(\Person.name, options: .new) { person, change in
    // we do get here
    print("I'm now called \(person.name)")
}

taylor.name = "Justin Bieber"

@objc class View: NSObject {
    var person = Person()

    override init() {
        person.observe(\Person.name, options: .new) { (person, change) in
            // we never get here
            print("I changed my name to \(person.name)")
        }
    }
}

let view = View()
let lewis = Person()
lewis.name = "Lewis"
view.person = lewis
view.person.name = "Lewis"
print(view.person.name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does the observer inside view never get called

There are two reasons (i.e. you've done two unrelated things wrong).

- You have permitted the observer to go out of existence. It is returned by the call to `observe` but you do not capture it and preserve it. So the observation ends before anything has a chance to happen. (You make the same mistake on the first observation too, but the fact that you are running in a playground hides it. This is another example of why playgrounds are the work of the devil.)
- You have substituted a different person (`view.person = lewis`). So the person whose name is changed is not the person we were observing; the person we were observing has gone out of existence already.

So, this rewrite will fix it:

```
@objc class Person: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var name = "Taylor Swift"
}

@objc class View: NSObject {
    var person = Person()
    var ob : NSKeyValueObservation?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.ob = self.person.observe(\.name, options: .new) { (person, change) in
            print("I changed my name to \(person.name)")
        }
    }
}

let view = View()
view.person.name = "Lewis"
```

Comment: Thanks matt :) I understand the second point clearly. For the first point, I hadn't appreciated that `observe` is returning an object that you have to retain separately from the `person`. It's especially confusing because when it's not wrapped in an object it works.  Anyway, I really appreciate your help on a not-great question

Comment: "It's especially confusing because when it's not wrapped in an object it works" But only because you were testing in a playground. There's no such _thing_ as "it's not wrapped in an object" in the _real_ world.